# Plane doesn't mirror correctly

Tags: modeling, retopology

[image]Hey,I'm trying to retopologyze the head but I can't do it because the plane doesnt mirror correctly

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symmetrize option doesn't mirror bones on the axis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194148/symmetrize-option-doesnt-mirror-bones-on-the-axis)

Comment: The origin (orange dot) is the center of the mirror. Right now, it's in the middle of the created plane. You need to move the origin to the center of the head where the mirror should start. There is an option to move it => https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/165421/107598